# Bash variable initialization

Tags: bash, shell, variables, initialization

Can variables initialized within if statement (or any other type of loop or function) conditions be used later in the script? The following code appears to be working... but I would like verification as I'm not use to this type of outcome.

```
if ( <true condition> ); then
    VAR1=1
fi

echo $VAR1
```

Real output: 1

Expected output: undefined (as variable has not been initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all bash variables are by default allocated in a global scope. You just need to be careful with subshells. Here's a working example:

```
$ cat foo
if true; then
    VAR=1
fi

echo $VAR

$ bash foo
1
```

In your case it will show the null string because you reference `VAR1` instead of `VAR`. Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to avoid those kinds of issues.